How to locate air filter in LENNOX gas furnace Model CX34-43C-6F-1
I can't locate the air filter in my home LENNOX gas furnace Model CX34-43C-6F-1 after 30 minutes search. It was installed in April 1991.
I attempted to send an email to LENNOX, without success because I am not one of their registered users.  They require a user name and password.
I can't find a LENNOX user manual from Google.  Probably they no longer produce that model.

Pictures will help.  Usually air filters will be near the end of the return air ducts before the air goes back through the furnace.

Or, as it was in my tract home in Phoenix at the other end at the return air grill.
