How to locate the air filter in LENNOX gas furnace Model CX34-43C-6F-1
I just moved to a Toronto house with a LENNOX gas furnace Model CX34-43C-6F-1 installed in April 1991.  Notwithstanding 30 minutes search, I can't locate the air filter.  Where can I find it?  I am told that I need to replace it every 6 months.

Same OP different account here : https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/310333/how-to-locate-air-filter-in-lennox-gas-furnace-model-cx34-43c-6f-1

I closed your other post as a duplicate of this one. Please consider merging your unregistered and registered accounts, which will allow you to edit, comment on any of your posts and most importantly accept an answer on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Have you got a picture? Have you checked the return grille?

the air filter would not be on the furnace, but as a return duct in the walls (large opening)

Air filters aren't standard by model, as they are usually outside the furnace itself, in the ductwork.  HVAC companies build the ductwork custom for each house.  This is why people are asking for pictures.  Even if we found the manual, it's unlikely that it will show the location of the filter.  At best it might show where the return is.

@DIY75 not necessarily.  Air filters can be located at the return grilles, or at the blower (air handler).  I suppose they could be located anywhere along the ductwork, but I've never seen that.  OP should provide a photo of the furnace and blower.
